# „-bash: fork: retry: resource temporarily not available“ on any command

Tags: command-line, 18.04, server, bash

first of all, this is my first post, so pls excuse me for any mistakes. My Ubuntu server is making some trouble. I cant run any commands from time to time. I get the error messages „-bash: fork: retry: resource is temporarily not available“ or „FATAL-> Failed to fork“. I tried raising die ulimits, the max pids and the max processes per user. The swapiness is disabled and i cant even turn on the swap memory since its a v-server. I cant even use the shutdown command to restart.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I‘d like to prevent a reinstall of the server. I‘ve seen some posts with this error on specific commands but i get it on any command im trying to run.

Comment: Sorry you are not getting any help. My only idea is that you have a root session running already, then see if it still works when your troubles arise. Sometimes there is still root room, while the user has hit a limit. Otherwise, you need to create some room for investigation. Maybe hold several tasks open, that could then be closed after your issue so as to create room for a few threads to poke around. search /var/log for any clues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually just reinstalled the server yesterday since i could figure out how to solve it. The server is running without any problems since then.